# "Enid Blyton" way to concede a point? Traditional upper class public school slang referred

Tags: dialogue

I need to change a line in a play from American slang to English.

Context - Character is uncertain about something. Others convince her with can you really see X happening? or Y?"

The character is scripted to say, "all right, I'll give".

But that feels extremely clunky and American (the playwright is American writing a British person). I feel like there's a much more Enid Blyton way to concede- probably public school slang fits the line and character best.

How would someone from an English public school (who attended in the 1900s) concede a point? Preferably slang. This is a comedy and although a professional, the character is quite eccentric and over the top.

Ideas so far: "All right, I'll give you that". "All right, carry on" "All right, I yield!" "All right, I give in". All right, I surrender/concede/submit/nudge" "All right, I'll say Uncle".

Unfortunately "fair enough" has only just been used by this character, or I would have gone for that.

Thank you so much for any ideas, folks

Comment: "You have a point" ? Not really slang, but at least it doesn't have that American feel...

Comment: You may want to ask this over at https://english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: definitely not "uncle". That is a North American thing.

Comment: I haven't heard British saying anything in particular to mean "you win". In both the USA and Britain you might hear "You've got me there."

Answer (score 1):

I was brought up on Enid Blyton. I don't have any books to hand to quote, but 'I give in', 'You win' and 'I concede' would all be in keeping with her style.

'I surrender' could work if the argument were forceful and/or the person felt ganged up on.

To make it more typical of the period, you could also add 'old chap' or 'old girl', e.g. 'All right, old chap, I give in.'